# AntMatcher issue with form login

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to understand how `antMatcher` and `andMatchers` work in Spring Security. I have the following code:

```java
http 
    .antMatcher("/admin")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("user")
        .and()
    .formLogin();
```

The problem is that it doesn't got to form login at all, it just opens the `GET` call as it's `permitAll`, no user password is asked for.

If I remove the `antMatcher` and use `andMatchers` it works. But I want to be able to create 2 separate filter chains and test with them.

Any idea how to make form login work with `antMatcher` and roles?

Comment: What URL do you call?

Comment: localhost:8080\admin

Comment: You solution should work. Show your logs with `DEBUG` log level for Spring Security.